# Python-How do i test for a second occurrence?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

Given a list of Python values xs and a value v, search through xs for v.
If you find a second occurrence of v, return that non-negative index. If v is not found for at least two
times, return the None value. The 2nd match is reported when multiple matches of the value are present

```
def find_second_occurrence(xs,v):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(xs)):
        if v in i:
            count += 1
            if v in i:
                count += 1
                if count == 2:
                    return v
        elif v != [xs]:
            count == 'None'
    return count
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tester3p.py", line 120, in test_find_second_occurrence_07
    def test_find_second_occurrence_07 (self): self.assertEqual (find_second_occurrence(['h','a','p','p','y'], 'a'), None)
  line 4, in find_second_occurrence
    if v in i:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @JohnCarter is the algorithm correct if there were a given list of positive integers? I'm also not sure what the error means and how to fix it

Comment: `if v in i` - `i` is an _index_. Your code is essentially asking if (say `xs = [10,12,13]` and `v`  is 12, then we start with `i = 0` as the first index) if `12` is in `0`. Does that make sense to you in any way? You can only use `in` for lists or list-like objects.

I believe you mean `if v in xs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here:

```
for i in range(len(xs)):
    if v in i:
```

`if v in i` is asking "is the value v found in the sequence i?"  But `i` is an integer, from the sequence `range(len(xs))`, and an integer is not a sequence, therefore `in i` makes no sense.

Comment: That makes more sense now thanks. But I also have another problem. When I put it in a test file it never gets to the elif statement. When the outcome was suppose to be 'None' , it just printed '0' instead.

Comment: Of course it never gets to the `elif`, because it crashes in the `if`.  Right?  Or have you fixed that problem and now we've moved on to another different problem?  If it's the latter, please try to debug it yourself and then post a separate question here if needed.